# Sensitive Progress Bar Retrofit

Tags: android, android-asynctask, retrofit, progress

I want to change the save button to show the download status instantly when the user clicked the "save" button in the image upload process in the Android application. In other words, when the upload is complete, the "save" button will show progress and the okey button will appear when the upload is complete.

What kind of structure do I have to use for this?

Comment: Please work on your English!!! I did not understand your question. Can you edit it and make it more clear?

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad English, I edited the article. I hope it's clear.